# Magento - Echo Attribute on Product Page

Tags: magento

In my Magento store I have created a new attribute with an attribute code of 'brand_info'.

How can I echo/print the contents of this attribute onto a product page ie. below the description?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure that the attribute is marked as "used in frontend", then in your template name write the following where you want to see the attribute:

```
<?php print $_product->getBrandInfo(); ?>
```

Answer (score 11):

To display the contents of attribute on product page you need to add following code in view.phtml file.

```
$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('brand_info')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

Answer (score 5):

Add the following code to your `catalog/product/view.phtml` or `catalog/product/list.html` template files:

```
echo $_product->getAttributeText('your_attribute_code');
```

Just change out `your_attribute_code` with your attribute code and you’re done.

Answer (score 1):

I found that adding to view.phtml was best for me

```
print $_product[brand_info];
```